# Accessing textlabels in a custom uitableviewcell created in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For my UITableViewController in my Storyboard I created a custom cell, with several text labels, which I want to represent the different data in my records. How do I select the various textlabels (I set each of the labels I want to change with different tags but not sure where to go from here) to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with tags, but I usually prefer to do this with a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. You only need to define some IBOutlets in your custom class's .h file -- you don't need any code at all in the .m file. Change the class of the cell to your subclass, and hook up the outlets to your labels in the cell. Then in code, you can refer to them just like you do for a standard cell. If your outlets were label1 and label2, then:

```
cell.label1.text = ....
cell.label2.text = ...
```

If you want to use tags, then you can use the method, viewWithTag: to get a reference to the label.

```
UILabel = *aLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: Thank you! The cells in my tableview are turning up blank however. - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InfoCell";
    SearchCell *cell = (SearchCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[SearchCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    Record *record = [self.workingDatabase objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: //set the content
    cell.myName.text = record.ABName;
    cell.myTarget.text = record.ABTarget;
    cell.myVendor.text = record.ABVendor;
    cell.myCatNumber.text = record.ABCatNumber;
    cell.myClonality.text = record.ABClonality;
    cell.myOrganism.text = record.ABSourceOrg;
    return cell;
}

Comment: @NLDK, if you log cell.myName or cell.myTarget, etc. do they return a UILabel rather than nil?

Comment: Hello rdelmar, I just posted a more formal question with where I'm at now with the code. And no, I just logged the NSString that feeds into the UILabel.text and the NSString is as it should be.